# iOS NSXMLParser can't read non-english chars?

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I have a xml file that contains some non-english characters. For example:

```
<item>Rīga</item>
```

When I parse it with NSXMLParser, and I get the first "**foundCharacters**", so I dont get the whitespace and the newlines. But when there is non-englis chars it only returns the first letter "R" as result.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: My bet would be you are not using the correct character encoding.

Comment: Agree with @trojanfoe, ensure you are using Unicode in your XML.

Comment: wrap non-english characters with CDATA tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

NSString *correctString = [NSString stringWithCString:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


 }
```

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
  {
  NSString *strValue = [NSString stringWithCString:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  [currentElement appendString:strValue];
  strValue = nil;
  }